# Can I have different modes for my shortcuts in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to have a set of shortcuts that I can use when I do web programming and a different set of shortcuts for when I do systems programming. Is it possible to easily switch between a set of shortcuts in vimrc?

Comment: The exact keyword is "filetype" not "mode" that means another thing quite precise in vim context.

Comment: BTW, buffer local mappings are the usual solution. Sometime it's also possible to have global mappings that call functions that have variation points based on the current filetype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure you can do it through [`functions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#41%2e7) or [`autocmds`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_40.txt.html#40%2e3) that create and delete shortcuts (or [`mappings`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map%2etxt), in Vim parlance). So you could do that easily.

But that is a little bit unusual. It is most common to have mappings specific to a given programming language. So if you use a set of languages for web programming and another set of languages for system programming, you should consider using [`filetype plugins`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#write%2dfiletype%2dplugin).

Comment: Ok, thanks! Yeah, I want to have shortcuts for HTML then have different shortcuts for let's say c.